# Maven TestNG - Edit Console Output of Execution Results

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have spent, not just today, but a couple other days too, of just research into this. Whether I am searching the wrong things with incorrect phrasing, or I am simply just misunderstanding some core principles, I don't know.

**Posting here is literally the last resort, since I have made zero progress in the matter.**

Is it possible to edit the console output to format it? This big red text all over the screen looks terrible and I cannot find a way of changing it.

[image]

Here, I have another test, that is NOT a Maven test, and when an execution fails, it looks so much cleaner:

[image]

I also notice in the "cleaner" one, there are tags:

> [VerboseTestNG]

Which also help to clearly define the end of the execution. Am I missing something that I cannot replicate this type of output?